# Remove the first and the last element from a list in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell

I am writing a small function which can help me get rid of the first and last element of a list. This is what I am trying to do:

```
>firstLast::[a]->[a]
>firstLast [x] = [ ]
>firstLast h:t = [i|i!= head[a] || i!= last[a]]
```

As you can see I am trying to use list comprehension here,but apparently I didn't use it properly.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Why not just this?

```
firstLast::[a]->[a]
firstLast [] = []
firstLast [x] = []
firstLast xs = tail (init xs)
```

Comment: Yes.. I simply forgot there is a function called init.. THanks!

Comment: Simplified to `firstLast xs@(_:_) = tail (init xs); firstLast _ = []`

Comment: the last line could be just `firstLast (x:xs) = init xs`